Data recovery from Iphone disk mounted to ubuntu
I managed to mount Iphone device to Ubuntu using ifuse as explained here
Now I want to do image recovery using photorec , when I run: photorec ~/iphone I get the following error:
Unable to open file or device iphone2: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Can you please tell me how I can recover deleted files from iphone connected to Ubuntu using photorec correctly? thanks

This is an IPhone issue maybe ask on an IPhone forum.

@DavidDE master device in my case is Ubuntu, Iphone is just a client here!
